# Passing parameter to a PHP script from javaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm fetching data from an API by using PHP Script and calling that script from javaScript file which loads when DOM have been loaded up meaning after DOM have been loaded by browser. The website which I'm working upon have multiple pages and each page have some data being fetched from API. For example - `A` page have data fetched from `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=1` while other page `B` have data fetched from API with `id=2`.

My PHP script is: -

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');


$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);


$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json';
$getfield = '?id=1';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
?>
```

My javascript code for fetching data: -

```
fetch('1.php').then(function(response){ return response.json();})
.then(function(data){ appendData(data);})
.catch(function(error){ console.log(error);});
```

After fetching data this make call to `appendData()` which I've already written.

On my website I've about 30 pages which make call to this API with different id's. I do not want to have 30 PHP scripts on my web server. Is there a way through which I can pass an id to PHP script when calling it with `fetch()` from `javascript`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to add a parameter to the URL that you're fetching from:

```
fetch('getData.php?id=1').then(...)
```

In your `getData.php` script check for the parameter in the `$_GET[]` array:

```
if (!isset($_GET['id']) {
    // Do something by default
} else {
    switch($_GET['id']) {
       case '1':
            // do stuff
            break;
       case '2':
            // do different stuff
            break;
    }
}
```